# SQLite: Filtering with columns that contains comma separated string values

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Is there a way to filter rows on table based on a column value that contains comma separated string values?

Example:

id | categoryIds

0  | 33,3332,335

1  | 334,3310,332

2  | 32,33,34

3  | 35,38,33

4  | 34,233,331

I want to get only the rows that is under a category id of `33` which are 0,2,3. I am thinking of using `LIKE` operator like this
`SELECT * FROM news WHERE categoryIds LIKE :categoryId || ',%' OR categoryIds LIKE '%,' || :categoryId OR categoryIds LIKE '%,' || :categoryId || ',%'`

But clearly that is incorrect.

Also need to handle cases where categoryIds column only contains single category Id (no comma).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `LIKE` clause to handle these cases:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE
  categories = :categoryId OR -- Single value match
  categories LIKE :categoryId || ',%' OR -- Starts with
  categories LIKE '%,' || :categoryId OR -- Ends with
  categories LIKE '%,' || :categoryId || ',%' -- In the middle
```

This way you cover all the possible positions the :`categoryId` (which in your case would be '33') can have in the comma-separated string.

Comment: This is almost similar to my approach but this will fail and will include 1 and 4. Thanks by suggesting the idea of single value tho.

Comment: try this : SELECT * FROM news WHERE 
  CONCAT(',', categories, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', :categoryId, ',%')

Comment: Thanks it work, tho need to replace CONCAT with `||`.